# Automatically add indexes in firestore index

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

Can i **automatically** add index in **firestore index**?

My app makes a **request filter** and **refers** to **firestore** for **display results**. But if **firestore can't display result,** in console i see **link** to **firestore** for **add index**. So if I **push** on the **link** in **Safari**, I will see how my **firestore adds an index**.

Can I **add this index** in the background work in the app, so I can continue to use the app, without **going to Safari?**

In the **future**, so that when each of the **error** indixes is **added automatically**.

I means this **index** in **firestore**:

[image]

And **error** with **link** example this:

`Error download results: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=9 "The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/*********/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgxQaG90b1N0dWRpb3MaEQoNcmV0cm9JbnRlcmlvchACGgkKBXByaWNlEAIaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAg" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/*********/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgxQaG90b1N0dWRpb3MaEQoNcmV0cm9JbnRlcmlvchACGgkKBXByaWNlEAIaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAg}`

Code that I use:

```
fileprivate func observeQuery() {

    guard let query = query else { return }

    stopObserving()

    setLoadingScreen() 

    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot {

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {

                let hallModels = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Halls in

                    if let hallModel = Halls(dictionary: document.data()) {

                        return hallModel

                    } else {

                        fatalError("Error!")

                    }
                }

                self.halls = hallModels

                self.document = snapshot.documents

                self.removeLoadingScreen()

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        } else {
            // firestore can't display result and i get an error with link
            print("Error download results: \(error!)")

            self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

In this line i get an error. I think in this line need write code if it possible, but i don't know how it to do.:(

```
        } else {
            // firestore can't display result and i get error with link
            print("Error download results: \(error!)")

            self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
```

And after i **add index** in **firestore** I stopped getting the **error with link**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to programmatically create composite indexes in this way, and you likely wouldn't want to. This should be part of your development flow when testing your code to identify if you need any composite indexes for more complex queries.

Luckily, this only needs to be done once for a new query you add.

Comment: But my app have many indexes, over 50+. it turns out that combinations can be more than 1000+ for add in index.

Comment: Single field queries are handled by indexes we create automatically, but if you are looking to query against multiple fields in an ad-hoc way (like reporting), then these really isn't a use case that Cloud Firestore is designed for. There is a 200 composite limit so you won't be able to have 1000+ combinations. Perhaps you're looking for something more like BigQuery on the backend.

Comment: @DanMcGrath Are custom indexes only needed when working with `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` but not with `==`? My own tests show that this is the case. But it's not clear to me in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), and I throught FireStore might have resently added this, without updating the documentation.

Comment: Composite indexes are only needing when querying (or ordering) across multiple fields where one field has an inequality filter or order by clause on it (and only one). Multiple equality (==) filters don't need one as we use a specific merge join algorithm to serve it using only single field indexes. Been this way since launch.

Comment: I downvoted because database indices should be deterministic in any environment. Plus, this is not a one-time database setup, indices tell the DB how the data should be organized and how it will be queried, meaning it can change (even frequently) over time. See below answer for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to automate the index deployment with the CLI (maybe in your CI/CD or beforehand so they have a chance to index all the documents before you deploy the app version that needs them).

When you initialize firestore in a project (i.e. `firebase init firestore`) a `firestore.indexes.json` file will be created. There, you can add all you composite indexes and deploy them with the following command: `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is much safer to know which indices are missing in another environment than to wait for the error message and damage user experience.